# jQuery FileUpload gem not initializing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I'd like to upload multiple pictures using the great jQuery File Upload in my Rails App.

So I followed the [Railscasts about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x23aIQPa-DY):

- Add the [jquery-fileupload-rails gem](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails)
- Add a require in my application.js
- Create a form for my pictures
- Initialize FileUpload in a file called "housings.coffee"

But I don't understand why nothing is happening when I try to upload multiple pictures, either using drag and drop or by clicking on "Add files...".

Each picture is saved normally when I push the "submit" button.

Please, could you help me? I'm really stuck.

Many thanks!

> application.js
>   ```

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require housings
```

> housings.coffee

```
$(document).ready( ->
  jQuery ->
    file = $('fileupload').fileupload
    console.log(file)
)
```

> housings/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@user, @picture], html: { multipart: true, id: 'fileupload'} do |f| %>
      <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
      <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="span7">
          <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
          <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: 'picture[image]' %>
          </span>
            <%= f.hidden_field :housing_id, value: @housing.id %>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
            <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
            <span>Start upload</span>
          </button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
            <span>Cancel upload</span>
          </button>
          <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">-->
            <!--<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>-->
            <!--<span>Delete</span>-->
          <!--</button>-->
          <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
          <!-- The global progress bar -->
          <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
            <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
      <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
      <br>
      <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
      <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
      </table>
  <% end %>
```

> housings_controller.rb > index

```
@picture = Picture.new(housing_id: @user.housings.first.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this can help anyone but I ended up implementing another javascript tool, [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

I thought it would be better because FileUpload looks quite old now and I had a headache trying to make it work.

Dropzone works perfectly fine with Rails and looks gorgeous.
As a reference, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).